# contact form inside colorbox request current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, colorbox, contact-form, current-page

I am using rails 3.2.8 and I have created a contact form from this tutorial:

http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/

Now I have this form inside a colorbox using

```
# Colorbox
gem 'colorbox-rails', '~> 0.0.9'
```

If I have this colorbox on several pages, how do I get it to also send with the customer info the page they were on when they filled it out?

Any help would be appreciated! If you need more info don't hesitate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that had to be done is in the contact controller add a line inside the create

```
@message.submitted_on_page = request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
```

before you deliver your messages

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to add contact form to your webApp or site is to install Dropifi Contact Widget (http://www.dropifi.com). They provide the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not looking for a product to purchase I am trying to solve this problem. I should have answer for this shortly.